# Behavior of reading and writing concurrent processes in C

Tags: c, synchronization

For this C project I have an input file containing positive real numbers and I am supposed to have two processes that read the file simultaneously (one  line each second): the first uses a pipe to communicate with the parent, the second one uses a shared file. The parent in turn should read from the pipe and the shared file and write the numbers into (separate) log files. I managed to synch reads and writes (although maybe clumsily), but when the processes finish reading the input they differ (the log from the shared file process misses the last line from the input). So one question is why is this so. The other more general question (if I can ask) is whether this is a viable way to synch these readings and writings, given that in the final version I am supposed to add a third reading process that uses a socket to communicate with the parent.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wait.h>
#define delay 1

void read_input(FILE *fpt, int type);

FILE *file_log, *file_log2, *shared_fp; 
int status, pipeFD[2];
pid_t pid, pid2;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
//initialize
    FILE *fp,*fp2;
    if (argc != 2){
    if (((fp = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL)|((fp2 = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL)) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);}
    }
    else{
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        fp2 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        }


    if (pipe(pipeFD) == -1){    /* creates a pipe */
    fprintf(stderr, "\nERROR: pipe() failed\n");
    exit(1);}
    shared_fp=tmpfile();
    file_log=fopen("file.log","w+"); /*open the 1st log file*/
    file_log2=fopen("file.log2","w+"); /*open the 2nd log file*/
    //child process with pipe
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0) {
        printf ("pipe process %d starts \n", getpid());
        close(pipeFD[0]);//close read end for child
        read_input(fp,2);
        return 0;
        exit(status);}
    //child process with shared file
    pid2=fork();
    if(pid2==0) {
        printf ("shared file process %d starts \n", getpid());
        read_input(fp2,3);
        return 0;
        exit(status);}
    //parent 
    if(pid*pid2!=0){
        double speed_pfc2,speed_pfc3;
        int count=0,tmp=0, pipewrote=0, sharedwrote=0, bothwrote=0;
        close(pipeFD[1]);//close write end for parent
        while(1){
            usleep(5000);
            //pipe process
            if((pipewrote==0) && (read(pipeFD[0], &speed_pfc2, sizeof(speed_pfc2)) >0) && (speed_pfc2>=0)){
                fprintf(file_log, "%lf\n", speed_pfc2);
                fflush(file_log); 
                pipewrote=1;
            }
            //shared file process
            if ((sharedwrote==0) && (fscanf(shared_fp, "%lf %d\n ", &speed_pfc3, &count)>0) && (count>tmp) && (speed_pfc3>=0)){
                fprintf(file_log2, "%lf\n", speed_pfc3);
                fflush(file_log2);
                sharedwrote=1; 
                tmp=count;
            }
            //if exit_sign break
            if ((speed_pfc2<0) | (speed_pfc3<0))
            break;
            //synch writes
            bothwrote=pipewrote*sharedwrote;
            if(bothwrote>0){
                printf("synch %d\n",count);
                pipewrote=0;
                sharedwrote=0;
            }
        }                   
    }
        wait(&status);
        wait(&status);
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(file_log);
        fclose(file_log2);fclose(shared_fp);
}

void read_input(FILE *fpt, int type){
    char *line = NULL;
    double speed;
    int i=0; size_t len = 0; double exit_sign =-10.0;
    while(getline(&line, &len, fpt) != -1) {    
        sleep(delay);
        speed=atof(line);
        i++;
        switch(type){
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if(write(pipeFD[1], &speed, sizeof(double))>0){
                    }else{printf("Write on pipe failed\n");}
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rewind(shared_fp);
                    fprintf(shared_fp, "%lf %d\n", speed,i); 
                    fflush(shared_fp);
                    rewind(shared_fp);
                    break;
                }
        }
        switch(type){
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    write(pipeFD[1], &exit_sign, sizeof(double));
                    printf("PFC2 wants to quit\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rewind(shared_fp);
                    fprintf(shared_fp, "%lf %d\n", exit_sign,i); 
                    fflush(shared_fp);
                    rewind(shared_fp);
                    printf("PFC3 wants to quit\n");
                    break;
                }
        free(line);
}
```

### Here is "input.txt"

0.34567

12.67889

34.78987

14.0.078

12.0092877

---

### Here is the output I get:

shared file process 9667 starts

pipe process 9666 starts

synch 1

synch 2

synch 3

synch 4

PFC3 wants to quit

PFC2 wants to quit

---

### file.log:

0.345670

12.678890

34.789870

14.000000

12.009288

---

### file.log2:

0.345670

12.678890

34.789870

14.000000

---

Comment: would be interesting to see what `read_input` does as I hope it would answer the question why do you call `fscanf(shared_fp, "%lf %d\n ", &speed_pfc3, &count)` instead of just using `"%lf\n"`?

Comment: @per_hero: you are right. I'd forgotten that piece. Now I've added that method.
I use the count variable to synch with the reading operations.

Comment: what happens if you change `14.0.078` in input.txt to `14.0078` or is it a typo?

Comment: It does not change. just a typo.